# T-SQL Advanced Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to achieve the following result;

| Customer | Purchase Total ($) |
| --- | --- |
| Customer A | 1234.56 |
| Customer B | 5678.90 |
| Customer C |  |
| Customer D |  |
| Customer E | 91011.23 |

The table structure is as below;

| Table Name | Fields |
| --- | --- |
| Invoice | InvoiceId, InvoiceType, CustomerId, DateIssued |
| Invoice Lines | LineId, InvoiceId, ProductId, Date, Price, Quantity, LineTotal |
| Product | ProductId, Code, name |
| Customer | CustomerId, Status, Region, Code, Name |

I have to arrive to the result with the following filters;

| Filter | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Product.Code | GTN |
| Invoice.InvoiceType | All invoices (Returns and Sales) are stored in the same table hence, in order to obtain correct result, I need to subtract returns from sales) **Sales Invoice Type is 8** and **Returns Invoice Type is 3** |
| Customer.Status | 0 |
| Customer.Region | London |
| Customer.Code | Starts with M |
| Invoice.Date | Year: 2022 Month: 10 |

What I tried:
I have tried a lot more other things and the below is my latest code where I achieved wrong results.

```
SELECT C.Name, 
    (SELECT SUM(IL.LineTotal) 
    FROM Invoice I 
    INNER JOIN InvoiceLine IL ON I.InvoiceId= IL.InvoiceId 
    INNER JOIN Product P ON IL.ProductId = P.ProductId
    WHERE IL.CustomerId = C.CustomerId AND P.CODE LIKE 'GTN.%' AND I.TRCODE = 8 AND YEAR(IL.Date) = 2022 AND MONTH(IL.Date) = 10 AND C.Code LIKE 'M.%' AND C.Region = 'London') -
    (SELECT SUM(LI.LineTotal) 
    FROM Invoice I 
    INNER JOIN InvoiceLine IL ON I.InvoiceId= IL.InvoiceId 
    INNER JOIN Product P ON IL.ProductId = P.ProductId
    WHERE IL.CustomerId = C.CustomerId AND P.CODE LIKE 'WLT.%' AND I.TRCODE = 3 AND YEAR(IL.Date) = 2022 AND MONTH(IL.Date) = 10 AND C.Code LIKE 'M.%' AND C.Region = 'London') AS TOTAL
FROM Invoice I
LEFT JOIN Customer C ON I.CustomerId = C.CustomerId
WHERE C.Code LIKE 'M.%'
GROUP BY C.CustomerId, C.Code, C.Name
ORDER BY C.Name;
```

Because it is required that only the totals of products those with the code starting with a certain letters are brought to the result, I cannot work on the Invoice table but rather the InvoiceLines table. Also because it is also required to list those customers who did not buy anything, I wanted to use the LEFT JOIN for the Customer table.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *Meaningful* sample data and expected results, ideally in DDL and DML statements, will really help us help you. The query you have doesn't look right at all; especially when you have 3 instances of `Invoice` all aliased as `I`, and some of the scopes are shared. You also have a `GROUP BY` yet don't actually aggregate *any* of the column in that scope, so why have the `GROUP BY` at all?

Comment: Also why `LEFT JOIN` to `Customer` when you require that the column `Code` *must* have a non-`NULL` value? It's impossible for the value of `Code` to be non-`NULL`  if no row was found.

Comment: I am trying to retrieve data to analyse monthly sales for specific items per customer. Part of the analysis require to also list customers who did not make any purchase for that month, hence I thought I could achieve that with LEFT JOIN. My knowledge of SQL is very limited so I apologise if it did not mean anything. All the GROUP BY Statements are there as SSMS was complaining without them.

Comment: `SUM(LI.LineTotal)` won't even work, there is no object aliased as `LI` in your query.

Comment: Sorry that should be IL. I've corrected it

Comment: Are you able to represent this in a SQL Fiddle please?

Comment: Aside: Code like `YEAR(IL.Date) = 2022 AND MONTH(IL.Date) = 10` is better implemented  as a range check, e.g. `'20221001' <= IL.Date and IL.Date < '20221101'`. It allows for the possibility of using an index. If `IL.Date` contains a time it handles the last day of the period up to, but not including, midnight. Example range calculation: `declare @Year as Int = 2022, @Month as Int = 10; select DateFromParts( @Year, @Month, 1 ) as RangeStart, DateAdd( month, 1, DateFromParts( @Year, @Month, 1 ) ) as RangeEnd;`.

Answer (score 0):

I did the leg work for you. Here's the SQL fiddle. You'll have to tweak it for all the specific variables and filters. It should be easy enough to add in other limiters where needed. I added a second `SELECT` that shows how to reduce the number of queries per row by doing `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s and using `CASE` expressions in the `SUM`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bb68a3/2)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Invoice (
  InvoiceId int not null
  , InvoiceType nvarchar(50) null
  , CustomerId int not null
  , DateIssued datetime not null
);

CREATE TABLE InvoiceLine (
  LineId int IDENTITY(1,1) not null
  , InvoiceId int not null
  , ProductId int not null
  , [Date] datetime null
  , Quantity decimal(19,4) not null
  , LineTotal decimal(19,2) not null
);

CREATE TABLE Product (
  ProductId int IDENTITY(1,1) not null
  , [Code] nvarchar(256) not null
  , Name nvarchar(50) not null
);

CREATE TABLE Customer (
  CustomerId int IDENTITY(1,1) not null
  , [Status] nvarchar(50) null
  , Region nvarchar(50) null
  , [Code] nvarchar(50) null
  , Name nvarchar(50) not null
);

INSERT INTO Customer ([Status], Name, [Code], Region)
VALUES ('Active', 'ABC Co.', 'Mega', 'London')
  , ('Active', 'XYZ Co.', 'Mega', 'London')
  , ('Active', 'TTL Co.', 'Mega', 'London')
;

INSERT INTO Product ([Code], Name) 
VALUES ('A1B2C3','Widget A')
  , ('D4E5F6', 'Widget D')
  , ('G7H8I9', 'Widget G')
;

INSERT INTO Invoice (InvoiceId, InvoiceType, CustomerId, DateIssued)
VALUES (1234111, 'Invoice', 1, '2022-10-16 00:00:00')
  , (1234777, 'Invoice', 2, '2022-10-14 00:00:00')
  , (1234888, 'Return', 1, '2022-10-16 00:00:00')
;

INSERT INTO InvoiceLine (InvoiceId, ProductId, Quantity, LineTotal)
VALUES (1234111, 1, 1.0000, 56.98)
  , (1234111, 2, 2.0000, 48.28)
  , (1234777, 2, 5.0000, 120.07)
  , (1234777, 3, 2.5000, 99.84)
  , (1234888, 1, 1.0000, 56.98)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE @GTN nvarchar(50) = 'A1'
DECLARE @WLT nvarchar(50) = 'D4'

SELECT
  c.Name
  , ISNULL((
      SELECT SUM(il.LineTotal) as LineTotal
      FROM Invoice as i
        INNER JOIN InvoiceLine as il
          ON il.InvoiceId = i.InvoiceId
        INNER JOIN Product as p
          ON p.ProductId = il.ProductId
          AND p.[Code] like @GTN + '%'
      WHERE i.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
        AND i.DateIssued >= DateFromParts(2022, 10, 1)
        AND i.DateIssued < DateFromParts(2022, 11, 1)
    ),0) --WidgetATotalSales
  - ISNULL((
      SELECT SUM(il.LineTotal) as LineTotal
      FROM Invoice as i
        INNER JOIN InvoiceLine as il
          ON il.InvoiceId = i.InvoiceId
        INNER JOIN Product as p
          ON p.ProductId = il.ProductId
          AND p.[Code] like @WLT + '%'
      WHERE i.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
        AND i.DateIssued >= DateFromParts(2022, 10, 1)
        AND i.DateIssued < DateFromParts(2022, 11, 1)
    ),0) --WidgetDTotalSales
    as Total
FROM Customer as c
WHERE 1=1
  AND c.[Code] like 'M%'
  AND c.[Status] = 'Active'
  AND c.[Region] = 'London'
  
SELECT
  c.Name
  , ISNULL((
      SUM(CASE WHEN p.[Code] like @GTN + '%' THEN il.LineTotal ELSE 0 END)
    ),0) --WidgetATotalSales
  - ISNULL((
      SUM(CASE WHEN p.[Code] like @WLT + '%' THEN il.LineTotal ELSE 0 END)
    ),0) --WidgetDTotalSales
    as Total
FROM Customer as c
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Invoice as i
    ON i.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
    AND i.DateIssued >= DateFromParts(2022, 10, 1)
    AND i.DateIssued < DateFromParts(2022, 11, 1)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN InvoiceLine as il
    ON i.InvoiceId = i.InvoiceId
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Product as p
    ON p.ProductId = il.ProductId
WHERE 1=1
  AND c.[Code] like 'M%'
  AND c.[Status] = 'Active'
  AND c.[Region] = 'London'
GROUP BY c.Name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bb68a3/2/0)**:

```
|    Name |   Total |
|---------|---------|
| ABC Co. |   65.68 |
| XYZ Co. | -120.07 |
| TTL Co. |       0 |
```